# Unity Container Vb.net LoadConfiguration Exception

Tags: vb.net, unity-container, factory

I'm currently using Vb.net in connection with the Unity Container model. But I can't get it to work.
My code is always failing in the Factory.

**unity.config:**

```
<unity>
 <containers>
   <container>
    <types>
      <type type="TestApplication.Interfaces.IBuilder, TestApplication.Interfaces" mapTo="TestApplication.Classes.Builder, TestApplication.Classes">
      <lifetime type="singleton" />  
      </type>
    </types>
   </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

I'm using a custom config source referenced in my App.config file.

The **app.config** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections> 

<unity configSource="unity.config" />
</configuration>
```

My **Factory.vb** looks like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Unity
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration
Imports System.Configuration

Public NotInheritable Class Factory
Private Shared registeredTypes As New Dictionary(Of Type, Object)

Public Shared Function GetInstance(Of T)(Optional asSingleton As Boolean = False) As T
    Using container As UnityContainer = Factory.GetConfiguredUnityContainer()
        Dim instance = container.Resolve(Of T)()
        If (asSingleton = True And Not Factory.registeredTypes.ContainsKey(GetType(T))) Then
            Factory.Register(Of T)(instance)
        End If

        Return instance
    End Using

End Function

Private Shared Function GetConfiguredUnityContainer() As UnityContainer
    Dim container As New UnityContainer
    container.LoadConfiguration()

    For Each item In registeredTypes
        container.RegisterInstance(item.Key, item.Value)
    Next

    Return container
End Function

Private Shared Sub Register(Of T)(instance As T)
    registeredTypes(GetType(T)) = instance
End Sub
End Class
```

The Factory fails at the line:

`container.LoadConfiguration()` in the `GetConfiguredUnityContainer` method.

`A first chance exception of type System.Configuration.ConfigurationsErrorsException occured in System.Configuration.dll`

I do have references to the mapped assembly. `TestApplication.Classes` also to the `TestApplication.Interfaces`
The interface is named `IBuilder.vb` and the class is named `Builder.vb`

References in the project:

Microsoft.Practices.Unity

Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration

PresentationCore

PresentationFramework

System.Configuration

Please suggest me any chances, I'd be happy.

Greets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after I checked some things over the weekend, I came to the conclusion that vb.net doesn't support an external unity configSource.

You could parse the config file with an xml parser and read each value. But I'm too lazy for that.

I edited my:
**app.Config** like that:

Inserted the container from the **unity.config** to my **app.config**

Code:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

  <unity>
    <container>
       <register type="TestApplication.Interfaces.IBuilder, TestApplication.Interfaces" mapTo="TestApplication.Classes.Builder, TestApplication.Classes" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```

I registered the type/s inside the **App.config**, after that I can read the container with my Factory, and can work with the unity container.